# Scons linking with LIBPATH

Tags: c++, build, scons

I've got a project with multiple directories which is failing to build. One of the shared libraries I need exists in 'build/debug/x64/eapi/eapi'. The correct path seems to be on the linker line but scons doesn't find it. All my libraries build correctly to a variant dir and are installed to a different common dir.

```
eapi is here: #build/debug/x64/eapi/eapi
HELP:
Dir('.').path 'build/debug/x64/eapi/example/example_Queue'
Dir('.').abspath '/root/cpp/build/debug/x64/eapi/example/example_Queue'
Dir('#.').path '/root/cpp'
Dir('#').path '/root/cpp'
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/debug/x64/eapi/example/example_Queue/main_durable_queuesub build/debug/x64/eapi/example/example_Queue/main_durable_queuesub.o -Lbuild/debug/x64/eapi/eapi -Leapi/eapi -leapi
/bin/ld: cannot find -leapi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


print(buildEnv['EAPI_LIBRARY_NAME']  + " is here: " + buildEnv['EAPI_LIBRARY_PATH'])

for p in ['main_durable_queuesub']:
example = local_env.Program(p, p + '.cpp', LIBS = buildEnv['EAPI_LIBRARY_NAME'], LIBPATH = [buildEnv['EAPI_LIBRARY_PATH']] )
```

Comment: You're saying that SCons doesn't find the library, or do you mean `g++`/`ld` can't find it? Does it work when you copy-paste the `g++` command line from above and execute it in a shell/terminal? Please clarify what exactly your question is (there are only statements above, so far ;) )...

Comment: Can you paste the output of: scons --tree=prune?  Perhaps (for some reason) SCons isn't seeing that the library must be built prior to the program?

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't appreciate it was putting 'lib' on the front and I was building with the prefix turned off.